# iAds: how to make real ads to generate revenue

Tags: xcode

Ok so i have created an app i wish to submit, i added an AD BannerView in my code, currently says Test Advertisement.

Now i need a real advertisement when i can generate revenue.

What do i need? how do i do it? Any tutorials? How to do i find and register to companies to put their Ads on my app, how does it work?

please give me as much information as possible please.
1- what i need (programs if any) or register to ad company if need?
2- any tutorials? what do i need to change in my code to get real ad in the same placeholder, instead of the test advertisement

thanks
Eden

Answer (score 0):

Apple manages and maintains iAds. You don't have to do anything but include the API in your app.

"Test Advertisement" may appear because iAds have not been rolled out to all countries. I'm not entirely sure, but I think that's the reason.